# To display selected object values in the input field

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an JSON file called `customers`, I am displaying the customers in the `dropdown`, In the `dropdown` when i choose the particular customer,How can i display the details of the selected customer in the input fields like this:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Customer">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id">
      {{customer.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" matInput >
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput  placeholder="Email" matInput >
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';
import { ICustomer } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  public customers: ICustomer;
  constructor(private myService: ContactService) { }

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.customers = await this.myService.getCustomers('');
  }


}
```

**Services file(contacts.service.ts)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ICustomer } from './models';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  private baseUrl: string = '../../assets/customers.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  public getCustomers(id: string): Promise<ICustomer> {
    const apiUrl: string = '../../assets/customers.json';

    return this.http.get<ICustomer>(apiUrl + id).toPromise();
  }

}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-ix7u5t?file=src/app/list/list.component.html)**

Comment: The StackBlitz is very useful for Angular questions, but please add the most relevant parts of code in the question itself, as links can rot, become invalid, thus losing value for next readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the template to this

```
<div class="main-div">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Customer" [(ngModel)]="customer">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer">
      {{customer.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" matInput [value]="customer?.name" >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput  placeholder="Email" matInput [value]="customer?.email" >
</mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I update your code with change event of mat-select

```
<div class="main-div">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Customer" (selectionChange)="update($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id">
      {{customer.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" matInput [(ngModel)]= "name">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput  placeholder="Email" matInput [(ngModel)]= "email">
</mat-form-field>

</div> 

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  public customers: ICustomer;
  name: any;
  email: any;
  constructor(private myService: ContactService) { }

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.customers = await this.myService.getCustomers('');
  }

  update(event){
    debugger;
    //alert(event.value)
    //alert(JSON.stringify(this.customers))
    let customer = <Array<any>>this.customers;
    let sec = customer.filter(c=>c.id == event.value);
    //alert(this.customers[event.value]);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(sec));
    //alert(sec.name)
    this.name = sec[0].name;
    this.email = sec[0].email;
    //alert(JSON.stringify(event));
  }
}
```

Code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-k9ib58